# Missing SPI1 in Output Selection Table?

Tags: pic, spi

In Table 11-3, p180 of http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000657H.pdf, there is no way to map any spi1 pins?!

I've gotten spi2 pins to work, but I need two buses and the part was specifically chosen because it had two spi peripherals.  Is the documentation lacking?  Is there something simple I'm missing?  Part of me is tempted to just guess every binary combo of 6 bits.

The errata here seems to have no helpful mention either: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/80000533g.pdf

Comment: Which device? The datasheet has many variations.

Comment: Sorry, the dsPIC33EP256MC202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing something. Page 3 of your first link sums it up quite succinctly:

> Only SPI2 is remappable.

What that means is: for a device with two SPI ports, SPI1 will be hard-wired to certain GPIO lines and you won't be able to change which ones they are.